# What is the scientific consensus on whether humans were monogamous during the period of evolutionary adaptedness?

Tags: human-evolution

The book *The Mating Mind* by Geoffrey Miller asserts, as part of its thesis, that humans were not monogamous in the [environment of evolutionary adaptedness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_psychology#Environment_of_evolutionary_adaptedness).

I found the book vivid and persuasive, but I'm interested in what others in the field would say. Is this the scientific consensus among evolutionary psychologists?

Comment: "during the period of time wherein evolution shaped our minds" - there was one distinct period?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its non-speculative aspects appear to be answerable by archaeology rather than biology.

Comment: @David Any sense of a better site on this network to ask this question?

Comment: Not really. There does not appear to be a SE list for archaeology. I just googled for archaeology list and there seem to be a large number, but which would be appropriate I have no idea.

Comment: There is no such thing as  "period of time wherein evolution shaped our minds". Our "mind" (whatever you mean by 'mind') is always evolving and has always been. It might not be enough to make your question on-topic but it would be already a good move toward it if you could just specify dates of interest.

Comment: I'm referring to the environment of evolutionary adaptedness; do you think this is a useful concept?

Comment: It might be worth expanding the question with some background.  For instance, are you asking whether there was a period when humans or pre-humans were "naturally" monogamous, and trying to discover when & how this changed?